# Free / Cheap Flash editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec, flash

This has probably been asked before, but here we go. I'm after Flash editor for Windows to create some simple animations for my website. Ideally I'd like something free or if commercial, not Adobe level prices.

Also, it would be good if it was user friendly, where by animations could be created more by a GUI and drag & drop, than having to learn ActionScript.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [SWiSH](http://www.swishzone.com/index.php)? It's been a while since I've used it, but it's a lot cheaper than Flash itself, and it does a fair few of the basic effects and things that people usually are looking for.

Comment: That's brilliant, in fact that's the exact app I was looking for. My brother used to use this years ago but for the life of us we couldn't remember what it was called, hence my question. Its name rang a bell as soon as I saw your answer, so when I mentioned it to my brother, the light bulb came on. So, you've done more than earn yourself a cookie, have the bounty :).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [FlashDevelop](http://osflash.org/flashdevelop) that is an open source project for developing ActionScript/Flash.

Comment: That isn't a drag and drop animation editor ;).

Comment: To be fair to Daok, he posted this before I added the requirement that I'd prefer drag and drop.

Answer (score 3):

The honest answer is that there isn't much out there. It's pretty tied up by Adobe, however there are a few:

- express animator - expressanimator.com
- koolmoves - koolmoves.com/
- Ajax animator - http://antimatter15.com/ajaxanimator/build/
- open source flash alternatives - osflash.org/projects

There is a slight learning curve to flash; If you are not familiar with traditional animation techniques like tweening then you'll need to learn about them, but it's not too hard.

Comment: nemof, thanks for your answer, much appreciated, certainly a lot to look at, but unfortunately EvilCookie came up with exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

ReadWriteWeb has Wix as one of its sponsors and has the following description.

[Wix](http://www.wix.com/) is a powerful Flash platform that enables millions of people to get online with their own custom Flash websites for free. At the heart of Wix is an intuitive drag-and-drop editor and an impressive range of fully customizable Flash templates. Users can choose from templates or create their Flash Web content from scratch, all with a simple click, drag, and drop.

Comment: Interesting, but that looks like a method for creating an entire web site in Flash. I'm just after creating some small animations on an existing site.

Comment: FYI there is also Windows Installer XML (WIX) which is something totally different if you stumble upon that.